# Issue with “Worksheet Change Event” in excel in combination with cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

That‘s my excel worksheet for project issues. Let‘s focus on the column E, the status of the work packages. Every work package can have one of the following 6 status (“ ”, ”Open”, ”Initiated”, ”Started”, ”Done”, ”Postponed”).

The single work packages are grouped in row 10 and 15 and via the formula the percentage of execution is given (E10 and E15). Every time a work package is set to “Done” the percentage rises.
And with this change in percentage of execution I want to trigger with “Worksheet Change Event” some further vba actions – but sadly it doesn’t work.

To make the following vba actions happen, I must go to cell E10 or E15 and hit the enter button… But I want the further vba actions to happen just by setting a work package to “Done” so that the percentage of execution changes and this should be my trigger for “Worksheet Change Event” (no hitting of enter buttons).

So see my code and my screenshot. And many thanks in advance for your hints.

[image: Excel visualization]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' grouping the single work packages of Range("E11:E14")
' and calculating the percentage of execution with
' =COUNTIF(E11:E14;"Done")/(COUNTIF(E11:E14;" ")+ COUNTIF(E11:E14;"Open")+ COUNTIF(E11:E14;"Initiated")+ COUNTIF(E11:E14;"Started")+ COUNTIF(E11:E14;"Done")+ COUNTIF(E11:E14;"Postponed"))
' in cell E10
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10")) Is Nothing Then
'Cells - Zeile, Spalte
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Here I want to code my further vba actions, which should be triggered via the change of percentage in E10 (for simplicity cell A2 get's increased by 5)
    Range("A2") = Range("A2") + 5
    Application.EnableEvents = True  
End If


' grouping the single work packages of Range("E16:E21")
' and calculating the percentage of execution with
' =COUNTIF(E16:E21;"Done")/(COUNTIF(E16:E21;" ")+ COUNTIF(E16:E21;"Open")+ COUNTIF(E16:E21;"Initiated")+ COUNTIF(E16:E21;"Started")+ COUNTIF(E16:E21;"Done")+ COUNTIF(E16:E21;"Postponed"))
' in cell E15
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E15")) Is Nothing Then
'Cells - Zeile, Spalte
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Here I want to code my further vba actions, which should be triggered via the change of percentage in E15 (for simplicity cell A3 get's increased by 6)
    Range("A3") = Range("A3") + 6
    Application.EnableEvents = True 
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Formula recalculation will not trigger a change event. You should monitor changes in E11:E14 and E16:E21 instead.

Comment: @Rory: Thanks for your comment on that issue and that recalculation will not trigger a change event.

Comment: @tueftla Maybe you didn't get Rory's comment: you need to replace `E10` and `E15` with the suggested ranges respectively. Of course, this will only work if the cells in the ranges are modified manually. If not, you have to dig deeper or use the `Worksheet Calculate` event which unfortunately doesn't have the `Target` argument.